# How to get hidden users in Youtube via api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Does youtube provide the ability to remove/add/get a list of hidden users?

We are writing an application to interact with streaming platforms.
Trovo and Twitch provide convenient ways to manage bans. It's strange not to find this on Youtube.

We are talking about hidden users from this support page:
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9482361?hl=en

Settings -> Community

Comment: Have you check the documentation? - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatBans?hl=en

Comment: After reading the documentation, I started my journey)
Unfortunately, I didn't find the answer.